# my phone may have virus but my antivirus scans clean that phon is protected

Tags: malware

A pop up window appeared on my phone ,about some wifi booster simuntaneously an other window got on and told that my phone was infected by an virus ,but my antivirus was active and then i scaned my phone but it was clean . Please explain did my phone really have a virus in it?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of advertisers try to mislead you by saying there is a virus on  your phone. I believe Google banned the use of misleading advertisements such as the one you are speaking of.  So if it was a pop-up ad, I would not worry about anything. Just be aware that some pop-up ads on websites don't have a cancel button, and if you press the back button on your device, it's like you pressed OK.